# which Newline Character works with Both C# and HTML at a time?

Tags: c#, html, c#-4.0

Hello I need Newline Character which works with both i.e C# and HTML
I know That in C# We can use,

```
System.Environment.NewLine or "\r\n"
```

and in Html We can use,

```html
<br/>
```

What is the alternative to this?

Comment: yes sir, i want to write log in log file and also send that log via mail as html body ,so it means i need to write two different statements instead?

Comment: If you need to send a log as an HTML e-mail, use replace: `logText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br>")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends on where you intend using that new line. For text files, use `NewLine` or `\r\n`. For HTML documents, use `<br/>`.

As you wrote in the comments:

> I want to write log in log file and also send that log via mail as html body.

So you would need to seperate the two cases.

For breaking a line in your log file, use `\r\n` or `System.Environment.NewLine`.

For breaking a line in your HTML body, use `<br/>`.

For using the log as an HTML document body, you can simply use:

```
string body = logFileConent.Replace(@"\r\n", "<br/>");
```

Where `logFileConent` is a string variable holding your text file lines.

Comment: thank you very much Sir, Currently this is work for me.logic is so simple and brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

Allright, use this type of strings:

```
"Debug: This is Debug 1 \r\n <br> Debug: This is Debug 2"
```

It will always display the `<br>` in the log file:
[image]

But the e-mail will only display a line break, if it displays HTML normally:

[image]

Comment: You might have to put an @ in front of the string for it to recognize the backslash. I don't know, haven't used it in a while.